# running app as a different user

Tags: macos, command-line, security, user-account

I want to start app N as user U2 while logged in as user U1.  The idea is U2 is less privilidged than U1, thus it would be safer to run suspicious apps.  Is it possible?

I tried `su U2; cd /Applications/N.app/contents/MacOS; open N` but that doesn't seem to work.  MacOS just pops up another terminal window logged in as U1 and strts the app from there.  How can I make it not do that?

Comment: I would recommend running suspicious apps in virtual machines.

Comment: One problem is that the `su` will open a new shell — but then it will wait for that shell to be closed manually before running the following commands (as your original user).  If you want to run commands as U2, then you can use e.g. `su -c "commands…" U2`.

Comment: @David Anderson, do you know how to set up MacOs as guest on a virtual machine?    Can you share where I can find out how?  I haven't been able to.

Comment: Which Mac would be the host? How much memory does the host have? What version of macOS would the host be running? What version of macOS would the guest be running. The newest macOS that I have had a guest run is Monterey using a 2013 iMac host. The host has 16 GB of memory and is running Catalina.

Comment: @David Anderson, let's assume that, for host, I have something that has enough resources.  And for guest, it doesn't matter what version as long as one that's somewhat modern (post cat names).  Where would I get the `.iso` file?  Or how do you make it happen?  I'd love to have a a disposable MacOs running in a VM

Comment: Under those assumptions, I do not know any answers to your questions. If you cannot (or will not) identify which Mac you are using, then we ain't doing this.

Comment: @David Anderson,  I have a bunch of Macs to choose from. to be the host. Let's say M1 Pro, 32 GB of Memory, MacOS 14.3.  Model id MacBoocPro18.3.

Comment: I have never had access to any Apple Silicon Macs. I best I could do is search the web for answers. This is something you could do yourself. From the brief searches I have done, apparently running macOS as a virtual machine guest is possible using Apple Silicon Mac as the host.

Comment: With regard to your question: *"Where would I get the .iso file?"*. With the exception of Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6), I have never used an `.iso` file to install OS X/macOS as a guest when using VirtualBox, VMware Fusion Player or Parallels on an Intel Mac host. I would assume the same is true for Apple Silicon Macs.

Comment: Parallels has an article titled [Install macOS virtual machine on a Mac with Apple silicon](https://kb.parallels.com/125561/).

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out.  Instead of using `open ./N` just use `./N` while logged in as U2.